# Maximum element in a binary tree

Tags: java, tree

This method finds the maximum in a binary tree. I have used generics to make this code more usable. However, I am not sure if I have written efficient and good Java code.

This is a method inside a class using generics and implementing `Comparable` interface for the generic parameter `E`.

```
private E maximumElement(TreeNode<E> root, E parentValue) {
  E max;
  if(root==null)
        max=parentValue;
  else {
    max = root.element;
    E leftMax = maximumElement(root.left, max);
    E rightMax = maximumElement(root.right, max);
    if(rightMax.compareTo(max) > 0)
              max = rightMax;
    if(leftMax.compareTo(max) > 0)
              max = leftMax;
   }
   return max;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't in a binary tree the max value be the rightmost one? Or am i messing sth up

Comment: @thi gg : That's the case in a Binary search tree

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### `static`, and possibly `public`

I'd recommend having this method outside your binary tree class itself. It can operate *on* a binary tree, but it's not a method that requires to be specified directly *inside* the binary tree. Also, it doesn't use any state other than what is passed through its parameters. As such, I would make it `static` and probably also `public`.

#### First call

It's currently a bit weird to call this method from the start, the `parentValue` parameter is used for further recursions, but what value should it be passed originally? Considering this problem, I'd separate this method into a public part and a private part, such as:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E maximumElement(TreeNode<E> root) {
     return maximumElement(root, root.element);
}

private static <E extends Comparable<E>> E maximumElement(TreeNode<E> root, E parentValue) {
     ...
}
```

#### General stuff

- It's good practice to always use braces. It improves readability and reduces the risk of bugs.
- Using early returns helps reduce indentation and makes it more apparent how special cases are handled (otherwise you have to scroll down to make sure that the value isn't changed)

Rewritten version with some additional formatting improvements:

```
private static <E extends Comparable<E>> E maximumElement(TreeNode<E> root, E parentValue) {
    if (root == null) {
        return parentValue;
    }
    E max = root.element;
    E leftMax = maximumElement(root.left, max);
    E rightMax = maximumElement(root.right, max);
    if (rightMax.compareTo(max) > 0) {
        max = rightMax;
    }
    if (leftMax.compareTo(max) > 0) {
        max = leftMax;
    }
    return max;
}
```

If you want to remove the `parentValue` parameter, you would need to introduce a null check:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E maximumElement(TreeNode<E> root) {
    if (root == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("root cannot be null");
    }
    E max = root.element;
    if (root.left != null) {
        E leftMax = maximumElement(root.left);
        if (leftMax.compareTo(max) > 0) {
            max = leftMax;
        }
    }
    if (root.right != null) {
        E rightMax = maximumElement(root.right);
        if (rightMax.compareTo(max) > 0) {
            max = rightMax;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

This repeated `!= null` checks and everything inside can be extracted to a method

```
private static <E extends Comparable<E>> E maxMaximum(E current, TreeNode<E> other) {
    if (other != null) {
        E otherMax = maximumElement(other);
        if (otherMax.compareTo(current) > 0) {
            return otherMax;
        }
    }
    return current;
}
```

Which leads to:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E maximumElement(TreeNode<E> root) {
    if (root == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("root cannot be null");
    }
    E max = root.element;
    max = maxMaximum(max, root.left);
    max = maxMaximum(max, root.right);
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Simon! Yes I have implemented in a way you have said about in the section First Call. I didn't think about static method :) Can it be implemented without considering the parentValue?

Comment: @ShivamSrivastava See updated answer for a version without `parentValue`

Comment: I am getting problem in implementing static methods as highlighted by you. E is a generic type variable and thus posing problems in static context. I have worked around the problems in the methods maximumElement and maxMaximum. However, the method maximumElement requires the root to be declared static . Now root is an  instance of a generic class TreeNode<E> and in the class BinaryTree<E> , I cannot figure out how to declare it static!

Comment: @ShivamSrivastava See update. If that doesn't work, try `<E extends Comparable<?>>`

Comment: After Muddleheaded sessions I overcame the problems ...yep the same way as now...and for the root part, I used wildcard which led to successful compilation . Thank you!